# Category as variant

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, category, products, variants

In Products (Craft Commerce), I've set custom fields. Some are texts, some are related to a Category. Actually, there's 2 different categories per variant...

In order to draw the  fields, I need to retrieve each category of each variant.
[image]

Looping thru variants to show text fields is no brainer, but I can't manage to get any category object.

Here's the variant definition:

[image]

And the code I put to show what's going on.

```
{% for variant in product.getVariants() %}
  {{ variant.id }} - {{ variant.sku }} - {{ variant.vendorLength }}
{# This show a CategoryQuery Object #}
  {{ variant.attributeGrainWay }}<br><hr>

{# This show a CategoryQuery Object as well... #}
{% set abc = craft.categories.group('woodGrainOrientation').relatedTo(variant.attributeGrainWay) %}
<pre>{{ abc }}</pre>
```

No matter what, I can't manage to get what I need.
Here's a sample output.
[image]

As always, your help is greatly appreciated.

Sylvain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't executed your category query. Add an execution method to the end of the query, such as `.all()` or `.one()`. https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#executing-element-queries

Comment: I can't believe my very eyes !!!! :D 
I'm good with PHP but obviously lack a few (a lot) notions of twig !
I think I tried different things, like variant.myObject.find() and craft.categories.group... without success... 
Sure enough YOUR SOLUTION WORKS JUST FINE !
Thanks again, a thank you for all of us sharing your knowledge to make other's life simplier ! :D